# structure of a p-group

Tags: finite-groups

Let $G=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_6\rangle$ be a non abelian group of order $p^6$ and exponent $p$. Also we know that $[x_i,x_j]=1$, for $1\leq i, j\leq6$, except $[x_1,x_5]=x_3$, $[x_1,x_6]=x_4$ and $[x_2,x_6]=x_4$. I want to find structure of such a group with two semidirect product